# Java Map.containsKey(ArrayList) returns false in one line and true in the next

Tags: java, arraylist, replace, hashmap, containskey

I have a `HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>`. I'm removing objects from the Map before replacing them, so I'm trying to avoid `put` calls which already have the key present in order to keep the Map size the same (for a steady-state Evolutionary Algorithm I'm writing from scratch).

The replacements are coming from an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfArrs`. Throughout some of my runs, the Map size has been decreasing because there have been duplicates present in this nested ArrayList. In the course of debugging, I've found this problem: the following code prints `GOODBYE` but not `HELLO`.

```
void updateMap(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfArrs) {
    //debug loop
    for (ArrayList<Integer> arr : listOfArrs) {
        if (mapObj.containsKey(arr)) System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
    for (ArrayList<Integer> arr : listOfArrs) {
        if (mapObj.containsKey(arr)) System.out.println("GOODBYE");
        mapObj.put(arr, 0);
    }
}
```

When I originally get the `listOfArrs` from a different function, I use `listOfArrs.removeIf(arr -> mapObj.containsKey(arr))` in an attempt to prevent duplicates, but it seems that's not working.

Comment: I have a suspicion that this is a nuanced Java thing that I don't know about to do with hash values, memory, Object pointers, etc.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're doing, but this `I'm removing objects from the Map before replacing them` has no point. `put()` will replace current object in the Map if it exists and return the old value without changing `map.size()`

Comment: As an aside, I recommend writing a "Chromosome" class to contain your arraylist, and let it cache the hashCode to avoid the cost of recalculating it. Assuming the integer is a fitness, put that into the chromosome too.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out - it's an obvious one. The listOfArrs contained duplicates that I didn't check for. When I'm iterating through that second for loop in the original post they start showing up because I'm checking the map after I've added one of the first duplicates.

Comment: suspected as much, but was writing a longer answer trying to see if `hashCode` and `equals` worked as you would expect in `ArrayList` (they do)